# How to perform compound queries with logical AND on array in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection the docs of which have an array property `members` which contains user IDs. I need to find the docs the members of which are a pair of user IDs, eg.:

[image]

From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#compound_queries) for compound queries I can see how to make an `OR`, but I need an `AND`, because I need the docs that contain *both* user IDs (which actually is what makes a doc unique). The docs say that

```
you can include at most one array-contains or array-contains-any clause in a compound query
```

so, the following code doesn't work (I tested and it actually returns an error):

```
const conversation = await firebaseDb.collection(collectionName)
      .where('members', 'array-contains', userId)
      .where('members', 'array-contains', otherUserId)
      .get();
```

I tried this as well:

```
const conversation = await firebaseDb.collection(collectionName)
      .where('members', 'array-contains', [userId, otherUserId])
      .get();
```

but it returns nothing.

Is it actually possible to perform a logical `AND` on array values in a Firestore doc?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution I can think of is to store those IDs into a Map and not into an array. So your `members` Map should look like this:

```
members
 |
 --- M1fB...szi1: true
 |
 --- wXam...69A2: true
```

Now you can simply query using:

```
const conversation = await firebaseDb.collection(collectionName)
  .where('members.' + userId, '==', true)
  .where('members.' + otherUserId, '==', true)
  .get();
```

And this is indeed an AND operation.

Comment: you'll run into indexing issues because firestore has to create an index for every uid. only 200 indexes allowed. also, these members are dynamic so no point in creating a map

Comment: @TimmySimons That's not correct, there is no need for any index in case of such a Query.

Comment: I actually just did the described approach and firestore returns a different index creation link for each combination of filters

Comment: @decoder That's the expected behavior. Each index has a different creation URL.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I commented because you've mentioned there is no need for an index for such a query, though in my case it did not succeed, I solved it, by leaving OR filtering in the backend then applying logical AND filtering on the paginated result in the frontend.

Comment: @decoder You need an index only if you order the results.

Comment: That is correct, I just tried it and it works great :D. Thanks @AlexMamo